# building python tkinter+pmw with cx_freez failed

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi. I have created a program in python which uses tkinter and pmw, I have build it with the cx_freez, every thing fine, it completes the building process, but when I try to run the exe file I got some path error, but that path is correct don't know why still I am getting the error, please any one can help me I have to give it to my customer as soon as possible. Attached is the error image 1.jpg

[image]

And the directory of build is 2.jpg

[image]

You see I have pmw foler in library.zip then why I am getting the error?

This is my setup.py code, the most common code to create exe.

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

exe = Executable(
    script="main.py",
    base="Win32GUI",
)

setup(
    name = "My App",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "blah blah",
    executables = [exe]
)
```

Comment: can you please show the command you are running from the command line to build the executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my first rule of debugging ("assume the error message it telling the literal truth"), it says it can't find a *path* with the literal name `*.*`. Do you have such a file with the actual three-byte name `*.*`? My guess is, no. I've never used cx_freeze, but I'm wondering if it's possible you used it wrong and gave it a file pattern where it expected a file or directory name.

Further evidence is that the stack trace is caused by a call to os.listdir, and listdir takes a *path*, not a glob expression, which is why you get the error that you do.

Comment: *.* means any file name with any extension, and there is __init__.py file in the pmw, so do you think still this error is logical?

Comment: @Aamir Adnan: I know what it means _in some contexts_. Read my answer again. The error message explicitly says it can't find a file named star-dot-star. It doesn't say "no files match pattern ...", again, your first step should be to take the error message 100% literally.

Comment: ok thats fine, could you now explain me if the pattern is right then why it is not finding the __init__.py file in pmw folder? (which is surely there), or in other words whats the solution? i have edited my post please check.

Comment: @Aamir Adan: The pattern is _not_ right because it's not using it as a pattern. It can't find init.py because _it's not looking for it_. It's looking for a directory path named `*.*`. It is literally looking for a _path_ named `*.*`, just as the error says. The error explicitly says it cannot find the *path* named `*.*`. There is something wrong with how you configured it, it thinks the directory where the code is is named `*.*`.

Comment: So how did become an answer? sorry but i have the same issue but i can't find a solution to this problem